# Can I connect a new PCI Wireless adapter dual band on my notebook?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bluetooth

I have an old notebook that can't reach more than 60mbps so I would like to change the PCI Wireless Adapter to a 802.11n and maybe with Bluetooth also.

The question is, my card have only ONE connector/cable:

[image]

Can I use a new card with 2 sockets connecting only one? (Without lose speed or bluetooth, of course)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot connect just one antenna lead to a two-connector card without losing speed or Bluetooth.